# Will a base class' method calls be directed to the derived class' overridden methods?

Tags: java

Given a class `A` which has two instance methods `x()` and `y()`, where `x()` calls `y()`, and a class `B` which extends `A` and overrides it's `y()` method,

What is the behavior of a call to `x()` on an instance of type `B`?

Does it call the `y()` defined in `A`, or the overridden `y()` in `B`?

Comment: Have you tried this ? What did you observe ?

Comment: It will call overridden `y()` method with instance of B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in doubt about what happens it's fairly easy to test:

```
static class A {
    public void x() {
        System.out.println("A.x");
        y();
    }
    public void y() {
        System.out.println("A.y");
    }
}

static class B extends A{
    public void y() {
        System.out.println("B.y");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    A b = new B();
    b.x();
}
```

The output is

> A.x
>   B.y

So you can see that is does call the overrided method.

Answer (score 0):

Child class method will be called . It means y() method from B will be called.

Reason is you did

```
  A a = new B();
   a.x();
```

So its a pointing to the object of B at run time.

If you do

```
 B b = new B();
 b.x();
```

it will be compilation error as b does not contain x method, hence compiler can not resolve it.